# Matching filters do not return results

Tags: views, search

I've created a views page of a search index (Drupal7). On this page are five search facets (using facetapi_multiselect).

- facet1 is filtering by an entity_reference field
- facet2 is filtering by the postal code

The problem:
Selecting a value for both facets (1+2) will never return any result, but there are matches.

Both facets are set to an 'OR' condition. Any ideas where to start debugging this?

Thanks, Marc

Comment: are your fields (ER & PC) added in admin/config/search/search_api/index/default_node_index/fields?

Comment: I'm using an other index for this search. Both fields are added there. The fields for the other three facets are also added there.

Comment: are your fields added in facets tab in search api settings ui?

Comment: also re-check that you add in ER fields nid or tid at the bottom of page in fields tab in search api page settings.

Comment: All of the fields are also active on the facets tab. But, the nid of the entity referenced field was not selected on the fields tab. I've activated it now. Is it recommended to index the id's of all fields used in facets, too?

Comment: Re-Indexed now, but no changes yet.

Comment: you are now in the right track, ER nid field is the one shoud be in facets tab, re-index every time you add or delete a field, in a few tryies you will succed, cheers

Comment: ER fields relationship must be added and well configured on your view, and use pane views, not block views

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! If I would use the IDs as facets, how can a user choose a facet by its value e.g. name?